# How can update chart in Google site when data is edited the Google spreadsheet

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites, automatic-updates

I have a data in spread sheet in a one column only with length of 1000 cell, this data is being updated every 5 seconds from another application. i want to show this data as a chart in a Google site such that the chart updated automatically when data is update. i try to use "onEite()" function . could any one has code example

Comment: How are you serving the chart? A published HTML with the vidualization library or a Google Widget?

Comment: i publish the chart as interactive first, then in google site i insert it and choose a live button, but it doesn't work for me . i try to insert it as a Google Widget then it appear in site but not updated.